# Android mobile browser - iframe in iframe

Tags: android, iframe

I have two iframes one in another that are works fine in all browsers except android mobile browser. When first iframe is loading from top window all is ok. When second iframe is loading from first iframe on adroid mobile I see message that there is 'Unsafe JavaScript atemp .. etc'. But why only on android?

Load frame like this:

```
var doc = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
doc.location.replace(options.url);
```

Url have long string with query GET params.

P.S. Both frames have same domain, main window is different.

Answer (score 0):

Following are known issues.

iframe is not working android inbuild browser how can resolve issue?

http://androidforums.com/android-applications/7101-android-browser-iframe-question.html
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?843814-Iphone-iframe-browser-crash-issue-anyone
For alternate you can also try jQuery Cycle if that suits your requirements.

You can also put `<iframe src="page-1.htm" name="test" height="120" width="600">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>` code in your page and test on various platform.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this posts, but they can't help me. First iframe works fine, but second is not. Thanks for the answer, I looked up iphone safari and it have same problem. jQuery Cycle plugin can't resolve my problem because I have something like facebook button, users deploy my button with javascript on some site and when somebody clicks on it m first iframe appears. I develop on Drupal CMS and second iframe contains form that is submitted without page reloading.